# How can I print only tcpsequence number with tcpdump

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I search for a way to limit or change the output format of tcpdump to print only tcp sequnce number, but i didnt find a way to do this.
Can you please advice?

Running on Ubuntu.
If there is no way to do this in tcpdump other ways to do this with some linux command is also good, but prefer a way to do this directly by tcpdump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -v | egrep -o 'seq [0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?|ack [0-9]+'
```

Using verbose mode, filter through grep to select seq and ack numbers.

For a more advanced solution, you can pass data on to the `scapy` library and write code to parse packets directly. The [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) may be a bit staggering if you're not used to network / byte programming, but the power is impressive.